# PHP Post XML Using CURL Encoding issue

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding

I am Trying to send XML CURL Request Using PHP with Arabic characters but have encoding issue!

I am using the below script:

```
    $input_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><request><Name>تجربة رسالة</Name></request>';
$headers = "charset=utf-8; Content-type: text/xml";
$url = "http://www.test.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $input_xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The encoding being correct once I tried to hit the request from Server's Terminal using the below:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><Name>تجربة النص</Name></request>' | curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' -d @- http://test.com
```

Would you please advice what updates should be done to PHP code so encoding works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$headers = "charset=utf-8; Content-type: text/xml";
```

To:

```
$headers = array("Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

It should work.